# Why is my server responding Method Not Allowed on GET preflight request and saying Allow Delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a .Net Core 3.1 web API that is set to allow all methods for my testing purposes.
When I run an HTTP GET request on a specific endpoint, I get *405 Method Not Allowed* and the response headers say *Allow: DELETE.*

All other endpoints in this controller and in my other controllers work as intended.

Here is my controller code:

```
[Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/User")]
public class UserAccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("ConfirmAccountEmail")]
    protected override async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmAccountEmail(string token, string email)
    {
        // confirm email code here...
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    [Route("DeleteUserAccount")]
    [Authorize(Roles = AdminToken)]
    public override async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserAccount([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        // user delete code here...
    }
}
```

And in my Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod(); // just for testing
    });
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoint(e => 
    {
        e.MapControllers();
    ));
}
```

Here's what my request (from Postman) looks like
[image: Postman request]

And here's the response headers I get back from my server
[image: Server response headers]

I have tried changing the Route and the HTTP type to POST (and passing the params as form-data).

I tried deleting that Delete endpoint, in which case I get *404 Not Found*. So that leads me to believe that for some reason, the controller mapping is binding a route to the delete method for my other route, but I don't understand why.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm at a loss as to what that is now.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Something to check: The call to UseCors must be placed after UseRouting, but before UseAuthorization.

Comment: Thanks, but that's how I already have it in the code above.

Comment: `protected override` don't you get compiler warnings for that?

Comment: @nvoigt I don't because my real code is implementing an abstract class. But, as it turns out, that was the issue as protected methods don't work as API endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run an HTTP GET request on a specific endpoint, I get 405 Method Not Allowed and the response headers say Allow: DELETE.

For this doc about "Action definition", you can find:

***Public methods on a controller, except those with the [NonAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.nonactionattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) attribute, are actions.***

Please try to modify `protected` to `public` on your `ConfirmAccountEmail` method, like below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmAccountEmail(string token, string email)
{
    // confirm email code here...
```

Comment: That's it! I was implementing an abstract class for other purposes and didn't realize protected modifiers don't work for API endpoints. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Often you can receive a CORS but the underlying problem has nothing to do with CORS rules. I would suggest trying this

```
[Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/User")]
public class UserAccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    protected override async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmAccountEmail(string token, string email)
    {
    // confirm email code here...
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    [Authorize(Roles = AdminToken)]
    public override async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserAccount([FromRoute] int id)
    {
    // user delete code here...
    }
```

}

i.e. to remove the `Route` attributes from the action methods and then test the endpoints like this
`GET https://localhost:4000/api/User` and `DELETE https://localhost:4000/api/User/1234`

Another option would be to remove the HTTP verbs attributes

```
[Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/User")]
public class UserAccountController : ControllerBase
{

   [AllowAnonymous]
   [Route("ConfirmAccountEmail")]
   protected override async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmAccountEmail(string token, string email)
{
    // confirm email code here...
}


   [Route("DeleteUserAccount/{id}")]
   [Authorize(Roles = AdminToken)]
   public override async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserAccount([FromRoute] int id)
{
    // user delete code here...
}
```

}

And then call the endpoints like this `GET https://localhost:4000/api/UserConfirmAccountEmail` and `DELETE https://localhost:4000/api/DeleteUserAccount/123`